# React-native Awesome project not building android project

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn react-native but am not able to build the demo AwesomeProject. I have set the $ANDROID_HOME variable in `~/.bash_profile`file. But every time I build it I get following error.

What went wrong:

```
 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
 Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
     file:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
 Required by:
     AwesomeProject:app:unspecified
 Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
     file:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
     https link     Required by:
     AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.0
 Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.pom
     file:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.jar
     https link
 Required by:
     AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.6.1 > com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.6.1
     AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.6.1 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.6.1
```

I don't know why it's looking in this folder file:

```
/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1
```

Installed sdk version is *23.0.1* still I am getting this error.

I have a dotnet background trying to learn react-native.

Comment: I had the same problem, did you follow the instructions exactly as laid out by Facebook? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html That is how I got mine to work, when I manually installed stuff without following the directions it gave me the same error.

Comment: I had to install Android Support Repository in Extras. It did the trick :)

Comment: To note, this has now been renamed to "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries".

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Finally got it. You have to install Android Support Repository in Extras, in the Android SDK manager

Open the SDK, scroll down to the last part, open the extras, select android support repository, and click on "install packages" here is a screenshot

[image: android sdk manager installing android support repository]

Comment: I bet you was missing that second screenshot right? I am about to do that too!

Comment: More specific instructions on how to install this would be nice